# Getting a Databricks drop schema error for delta table

Tags: sql, databricks

I have a delta table schema that needs new columns/changed data types (Usually I do this on non delta tables and those work fine)
I have already dropped the existing delta table and tried dropping the schema and getting a 'v1 session catalog' error.
I am currently using SQL, 10.4 LTS cluster, spark3.2.1, scala 2.12 (I cant change these computes), driver and workers are standard E_v4

What I already did, and worked as usual

> drop table if exists dbname.tablename;

What I wanted to do next:

> drop schema if exists dbname.tablename;

The error I got instead:

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Nested databases are not supported by v1 session catalog: dbname.tablename

When I try recreating the schema in the same location I get the error:

> AnalysisException: The specified schema does not match the existing schema at dbfs:locationOfMy/table
> ... Differences
> -Specified schema has additional fields newColNameIAdded, anotherNewColIAdded
> -Specified type for myOldCol is different from existing schema ...
> If your intention is to keep the existing schema, you can omit the
> schema from the create table command. Otherwise please ensure that
> the schema matches.

How can I do the schema drop and re-register it in same location and same name with new definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering a month later since I didnt get replies and found the right solution;

Delta files have left over partitions and logs that cannot be updated using the drop commands. I had to manually delete the logs depending on where my location was.

Comment: Would a VACUUM clean the leftovers partitions and logs ?
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-vacuum.html

Comment: No, vacuum does not work. I also tried a few other things repairs, refreshes, they didnt work either. I still continue to delete them from storage

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

dbutils.fs.rm(path, True)

Use the path of your schema.

Then create your table again.