Databricks: create table using delta table path giving AnalysisException: The specified schema does not match existing schema at dbfs:/mnt/datalake/
I have have a Delta Table Path. Based on this, I am trying to create table using
create table if not exists dbo.DimCustomer
(CustomerSK BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
first_name varchar(128),
 last_name  varchar(128),
  HashKey       binary,
  DWIsEncryptedFl tinyint,
  DWCreateDt timestamp NOT NULL,
  DWLastUpdateDt timestamp NOT NULL)
USING DELTA location '/mnt/datalake/prepped/dimcustomer.delta/'  
  TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.columnMapping.mode' = 'name',     'delta.minReaderVersion' = '2',     'delta.minWriterVersion' = '5')

This gives AnalysisException:
The specified schema does not match the existing schema at dbfs:/mnt/datalake/prepped/dimcustomer.delta
and it suggests to use String for first_name, last_name.
However when I used String to replace, then again it fails with same error, but this time it suggests to use varchar(128)
Unable to fix the issue.
Any help will be hugely appreciated.
Tried to Diagnose Error and the solution provided but didn't work

could you please provide dimcustomer.delta sample data?

Maybe cleaning up the leftover logs and partitions could help as suggested by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74185620/9076030

First, create the table without specifying the columns as below
create table if not exists dbo.DimCustomer 
USING DELTA location '/mnt/datalake/prepped/dimcustomer.delta/'  
TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.columnMapping.mode' = 'name','delta.minReaderVersion' = '2','delta.minWriterVersion' = '5')

And from that table figure out what is missing. If you need to enforce the datatype figure out the size and re-create the same table.
